# How to track facebook installs on a Hybrid App

Tags: facebook, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to add the tracking of installs for my Hybrid Mobile app but the code provided to me is only native for iOS and Android thus I cannot apply this to my project..

[image: Install Tracking]

Is there a method I need to invoke from the Facebook SDK? I have integrated it already with my application as I utilize the Facebook Login. According to the guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk because it is a hybrid app it should automatically be tracked but this is not the case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with "hybrid" app? What system are you using? You are not using any Facebook SDK? How are you implementing Facebook Login? If you use Javascript; install tracking is not supported from the JS sdk.

Comment: I am using the Facebook SDK as i utalize a Facebook Login option when logging into the app - a hybrid app is a Cordova app, compile across all platforms etc

Comment: @Daniel have you got any solution for this?